# Microsoft Store API reports PEX-CatalogAvailabilityDataNotFound

Tags: microsoft-store

While rewriting/testing a WPF app with Microsoft Store Addons, the purchase flow test of our test Addon stopped working reporting the error `PEX-CatalotAvailabilityDataNotFound` after completion of the Store Purchase dialog (see image below):

[image]

The parent application had its certification revoked because of a change in Store Certification guidelines and we are testing purchase flow prior to re-submitting the application to the Store.  But the test Addon has been active for months afterwards.

Found a support answer that this sometimes happens [when the API call times out because the connection is slow or client date/time is too divergent from the Store's](https://windowsreport.com/pex-catalog-availability-data-not-found/) but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your addon is not or appears to your app's request to not be in the Store. [This answer to this PEX-CatalogAvailabilityDataNotFound error](https://windowsreport.com/pex-catalog-availability-data-not-found/) explains this can happen when your Internet connection is slow and your request times out. Or it can be that your computer date and time are too far off from (in advance of) the Store's date/time.

But it can also happen when your app is pulled from the MSFT Store. The associated addons will eventually be pulled as well (it can take weeks).

The bottom line - your request of the Store API in some way returns unable to find your addon.